# Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 can't get files with white spaces

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-s3

On a project i'm currently working we are using Zend frameworks Amazon S3 service to get and send files into an S3 bucket.

Everything works great except when we try to get a file that has white spaces in its name, no problems storing files.

Basically we can't get files with blank spaces in the name.

Is this familiar to anyone?

Comment: Do you url encode your file-names before sending the request?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but it fails. I should not be necessary because the framework is taking car of it at some point.